# Compiling separate bibliographic files for a single document

Tags: bibliographies

I have a code which goes like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,mathtools,cleveref,xfrac,subcaption,multirow,multicol,amssymb,mathptmx,fancyhdr,natbib,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{floatpag}\floatpagestyle{empty}
\crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}
\crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\crefname{section}{Sect.}{Sects.}
\crefname{subsection}{Sect.}{Sects.}
\crefname{table}{Tab.}{Tabs.}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[top=30mm,bottom=27mm,left=30mm,right=25mm,textheight=240mm,textwidth=160mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.5pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{12mm}
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}{}
\fancyhead{}% clear default headers
\fancyhead[L]{\ifnum\value{section}=0\relax
    \else \nouppercase{\leftmark}
    \fi}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
    \input{chapter0}
    \input{chapter1}
    \input{chapter2}
    \input{chapter3}
    \input{chapter4}
    \input{chapter5}
    \input{chapter6}
    \newpage
    \fancyhead[L]{Bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{first_citations}      
    \vfill
    (Candidate name)
    \hfill
    (Guide name)\\
    Candidate
    \hfill
    Guide
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \newpage
    \fancyhead[L]{Synopsis}
    \input{chapter7}    
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{second_citation}  
    \vfill
    (Candidate name)
    \hfill
    (Guide name)\\
    Candidate
    \hfill
    Guide
\end{document}
```

From chapter0 to chapter6, the corresponding bib file is first_citations and only for chapter7 the corresponding bib file is second_citation. So, what I want is after chapter 6, the bibliography file first_citations should be printed and after chapter seven I want to get second_citation **ONLY** to be printed. But, only first_citations is getting printed on both instances.

When I comment from `\input{chapter0}` to `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \newpage` I can see that second_citation is being printed, but when I am combining all the files, I am not getting what I required.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the `bibunits` package to handle the two bibliographies.
Wrap the first 7 chapters in a `bibunit` environment, i.e.,

```
\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
\input{chapter0}
...
\input{chapter6}
\putbib[first_citations]
...
\end{bibunit}
```

and  do the same for the seventh chapter

```
\begin{bibunit}[plainnat]
\input{chapter7}
\putbib[second_citation]
...
\end{bibunit}
```

then the workflow to compile the file and the bibliographies is

```
latex main
bibtex bu1
bibtex bu2
latex main
latex main
```

Comment: many thanks for taking time to look into my issue. But i believe, \begin{bibunit}[plainnat] rather than \begin{biunit}[plainnat] in the beginning of the second part of codes.

But nevertheless, did not get what do you mean by bibtex bu1 and bibtex bu2?

I am using TexStudio i made a user command after going to "Options"-> Configure TexStudio-> Build and added user defined command "txs:///latex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///latex | txs:///latex". But no bibliographies are coming?

Comment: You have to specify different file names for bibtex. They should be `bibtex bu1` and `bibtex bu2`. You can try from command line

Comment: I have made seperate files "chapter0" to "chapter7" with 2 separate bib files "first_citations" & "second_citation" along with a main file where I have written all codes that I have mentioned along with the suggestions that you have given. Then I opened command prompt and navigated to the folder. Then I typed: latex document, bibtex bu1, bibtex bu2, latex document, latex document in succession.

I hope this is what you asked me to do. But still bibliographies are not coming...

Comment: Have you added `\usepackage{bibunits}` in the preamble, and run `pdflatex` twice after running `bibtex`?

Comment: Now it's **perfect**. Instead of  latex document, one should run `pdflatex document` in the command prompt. And yes, I had already added `\usepackage{bibunits}` in the preamble. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Anybody who is wondering how to incorporate bibtex bu1 and bibtex bu2 in **TexStudio**, see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227879/problem-using-bibunits)

Comment: All was working fine with the help i received from this and from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227879/problem-using-bibunits). But when I added one more extra citation in bib it was not compiling properly. So I had to run commands in command line to update bu1.bbl file. I am not sure why is this happening.