# Automating BIBTeX Processing of Multiple bux.aux Files of bibunits Package

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, bibunits

I'm using texmaker on Windows, and bibunits to create multiple bibliographies. Now, the package creates a `bux.aux` file for each inserted `bibunit` environment, and of course bibtex has to process every `.aux` in a single run. So, the package's documentation provides a CShell script to automate this process which is as follows:

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach auxfile (bu*.aux)
    echo bibtex ‘basename $auxfile .aux‘
    bibtex ‘basename $auxfile .aux‘
end
```

I want to know how can I use this command inside texmaker, that is how to integrate the script file `.csh` in the "User" option of "Quick Build" command when configuring texmaker. Currently I have `bibtex bu1.aux|bibtex bu2.aux %` as to run only two of them.

Comment: Instead of trying to convince texmaker to run your script, it might be easier to use one of the tex automation tools to automatically run all the necessary step? Have a look at e.g. latexmk. Or if you need more control, give arara a try. With arara you can specify in your document which tools should be run

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227879/problem-using-bibunits/678151#678151

Comment: Thanks again this will really help.

Comment: You're welcome!